# Latitude and Longitude conversion error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to execute a specific query in my database, but occurs the following error

**Table San_Filial**

```
Filial_Id   Name    lat            lon
2           A       -19.926131     -43.924373
3           B       -19.952192     -43.938789
4           C       -19.939626     -43.924541
5           D       -19.95529      -43.92953
6           E       -19.9099       -43.93124
7           F       -19.926191     -43.946067
9           G       -19.97125      -43.96622
14          H       -19.89038      -43.921734
17          I       -19.88838      -43.93059
19          J       -19.94305      -43.94093
```

**Query**

```
SELECT *
FROM San_Filial 
WHERE San_Filial.Credenciada_Id IN (2,3,4,5,6,7,9,14,17)
AND ACOS(COS(RADIANS(ltrim(San_Filial.lat))) 
* COS(RADIANS(convert(float, -19.926131))) 
* COS(RADIANS(ltrim(San_Filial.lon)) 
- RADIANS(convert(float, -43.924373))) 
+ SIN(RADIANS(ltrim(San_Filial.lat))) 
* SIN(RADIANS(convert(float, -19.926131)))) * 6380 < 5.0
```

**Error**

```
Mesage 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to float.
```

Someone can help me ?

Comment: Try using both `LTRIM & RTRIM` AS `RTRIM(LTRIM(San_Filial.lat))` and `RTRIM(LTRIM(San_Filial.lon))` for both fields

Comment: Doesn't work. But look, if in my WHERE clause I put WHERE San_Filial.Credenciada_Id IN (2,3,4,5,6,7,9,14,17), WORKS FINE, but if I put WHERE San_Filial.Credenciada_Id IN (2,3,4,5,6,7,9,14,17,19) doesn't work. So, we can thought that the FILIAL_ID 19, is the problem, but if I put like this WHERE San_Filial.Credenciada_Id IN (19,3,4,5,6,7,9,14,17) WORKS ALSO. So, to resume, if I put in my WHERE clause 9 ID's, works, IF I put 10 ID's, dont.

Comment: Check the data for `lon` and `lat` `where San_Filial.Credenciada_Id = 19`

Comment: *BTW*, what is `San_Filial.Credenciada_Id` which is not in the shown table. I tried [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56a05/3) your data with `San_Filial.Filial_Id IN` and works.

Comment: Filial_Id and Credenciada_Id has the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by seeing if you have any data that is not in a correct format:

```
select *
from san_filia1
wHERE San_Filial.Credenciada_Id IN (2,3,4,5,6,7,9,14,17) and
      (isnumeric(lat) = 0 or isnumeric(long) = 0)
```

From this, you'll see what is causing the problem and then you can fix it.

The correct fix is probably along these lines:

```
select *
from (select sf.*,
             (case when isnumeric(lat) then cast(lat as float) end) as latf,
             (case when isnumeric(long) then cast(long as float) end) as longf
      from san_filial sf
     ) sf
where . . . -- use Latf and Longf instead of lat and long
```

You need to do the conversion inside a `case` statement to guarantee that it works as expected.  SQL does not guarantee the ordering of statements and a filter might be applied *after* the calculation.

Comment: I'm trying like this, `select *
from (select sf.*,
             (case when ISNUMERIC(sf.lat) = 1 then cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(sf.lat)) as float) end) as latf,
             (case when isnumeric(sf.lon) = 1 then cast(LTRIM(RTRIM(sf.lon)) as float) end) as longf
      from san_filial sf
     ) sf` but occurs the same error